# Virtual Box: Critical error while running the Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, virtualbox, kali-linux

I try to create Linux Kali on Mac with using VirtualBox. And I want to run android emulator on this Virtual Box.

My VirtualBox settings look like:
[image]

[image]

After all, I installed android-studio and I've tried to run android emulator but it gives error like:

```
A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and machine
execution has been stopped...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox is not recommended.

> it seems that android emulator inside vm's using VirtualBox has
> historically had a lot of issues. It seems most of the recommendations
> are to either use VMWare, Hypver-V, or just install the emulator
> natively on your base machine.
> **Ring Zero Labs**

Installed VMWare and solved.